# Does image/css/js transfer add to the 'Service request time' limit

Tags: sandbox

“Service request time” is calculated as the total server time in minutes required to generate pages for the site.

Would anyone know if that includes the transfer time of images/css/js files or only the processing needed to render the pages.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the http transfer is not counted, I have loaded up a large image, and fully reloaded it multiple times in the browser and have not found the counter in `Sites` > `Site Name` > `24 Hour Usage History` section to update.

[image]